# Bash Convert 2 files into an associative array

Tags: bash

Using Bash 3.2, how could I read two sets of files, into an array, where the first array is a key for the value ( which is specified by the second set of array ). Each file correlates to each other. So 0 in file one, is the key for 0 in file 2.

file 1:

```
fruit
veggies
meat
```

file 2:

```
apples
carrots
pork
```

How would I read both files and make the array look like this:

```
$ARRAY[fruit] = apples
$ARRAY[veggies] = carrots
$ARRAY[pork] = meat
```

---

**EDIT**: Intended useage (since Bash 3.2 doesn't have associave arrays)

I have a file with ids, and a file with access tokens. I was planning on building an array that looked like this:

```
$ARRAY[id] = that id's token
```

Then loop through the array, and hit an url, like this:

```
curl https://a.service/$ID?token=$TOKEN
```

---

I'd searched around for a little while, couldn't find any clear examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since `bash` 3.2 doesn't have associative arrays, you'll have to specify how you were planning to use the array to provide a good alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it all together, based on @anubhava's `paste` approach:

```
 paste file1 file2 | 
   while read ID TOKEN; do curl "https://a.service/$ID?token=$TOKEN"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately **there are no associative arrays in bash before version 4**. You can use awk though:

```
paste f1 f2|awk '{a[$1]=$2} END {for (i in a) print i "=" a[i]}'
meat=pork
fruit=apples
veggies=carrots
```

**EDIT:** As per your edited question you can just do `paste` and process resulting file/data:

```
paste f1 f2
meat pork
fruit apples
veggies carrots
```

Comment: @John1024: I very well know about BASH4 associative array but OP started with `Using Bash 3.2`

Comment: I should have known that you would have caught a detail that I missed.

Comment: You didn't miss much I think. I don't think other than awk there is any other native way to use associative arrays in BASH 3.2

Comment: You really should say "there are no associative arrays in bash before version 4". People may read this answer without fully understanding the context of the question.

Comment: Thanks very valid point. I realize my language was confusing to somebody who didn't read the question.